# Hide wwsd section based in one att

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

How can I hide/show a WWSD detail's section based on the value of one attribute?

I already tried:

```
SectionName.Visibe = true/false
```

in the Load and Start events.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and worked fine for me. Make sure that you are programming on the events of the DETAIL and not one of the sections.

[image: Detail selected]

In my example I used this code:

```
If Transaction1Id = 1
    Section2.Visible = False
Else
    Section2.Visible = True
EndIf
```

`Transaction1Id` is an attribute from the transaction and `section2` is one of the sections on the `WorkWithDevices`.

Comment: Hi Sebadrc, yes I was put the code inside the section before but now as your indication I put in the Detail but I got the "error: Invalid attribute 'Photos' (Events, WWSD01, Line: 7, Char: 2, Detail#1" and 
"error: 'Visible' invalid property." when I try to save the WWSD, the Photos is my section name .

Comment: Hi Sebadrc, I try using inside the IF "Section.Transaction2.Visible = False",   "Transaction2.Visible = False", "General.Visible = False" and "Section2.Visible = False" but all of these tentatives are incorrect because I cannot save the WWSD, using your example above, can you please write exactly what I need put inside the IF to hide the "Section (Transation2)" based in the "TransactionId = 1" ? thx.